# react useEffect doesn't recognize object change (router history)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm changing the url of one of my routes based on search filters the user is using. My component rerenders properly after every change and I am able to check my url like this

```js
// works as expected (logs the history obj on every rerender)
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('rerender', history);
});
```

however when I try to only let this run when history updates nothing happens

```
//doesnt run ever
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('rerender', history);
}, [history]);
```

history is passed in by router as a prop and I can confirm that it changes.

Comment: Though I'm not 100% sure, I think it is because the object reference stays the same even if its contents changed. I would advice putting in for example `history.url` (or however you reach it) so that it knows to specifically check for a difference in the url.

Comment: @ApplePearPerson yeah that was it since I used `history.push` if you put it as an answer I can mark it as correct

Comment: Done. Is it actually `history.url`?

Comment: @ApplePearPerson `history.location` or in my case `history.location.search`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of the history object change, but the object reference itself stays the same. This means react will not see it as a change. If you want to specifically check for a change in URL, you should put that in the dependency array like so `[ history.location ]`.